# How to make an image of a <ImageBackground> tag darker (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create an image with a text on it, and in order for the the text to be clearly seen I need to make the image darker.
Also (don't sure if it matters or not) I need the background image to be touchable.
This question was asked several times here and I've seen some answers, but none of them worked for me, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something more crucial here.

My code is the following:

```
<View style={postStyles.container}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
this.props.navigation.navigate('AnotherWindow')}>
    <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/my_img.jpg')} 
     style={{width: '100%', height: 150}}>
            <Text style={postStyles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
                My text
             </Text>
    </ImageBackground></TouchableOpacity>
```

From looking around here, I've tried the following solutions:

- Tried to wrap the text element inside the imagebackground tag inside a 
   View element that has a style property of "backgroundColor" with value of 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)' (also tried different values),
- Tried to add this backgroundColor property to the styles of both the container itself, the TouchableOpacity element
- Tried to above two solutions with the "elevation" property instead of backgroundColor (I work in Android).

None of the above solutions worked, in a sense that the background image didn't change at all, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something more crucial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to make the image darker, you'll need the `Image` component and use the tintColor prop like:

```
<Image source={require('./your_image.png')} style={{ tintColor: 'cyan' }}>
```

this `tintColor` prop only works for `Image` component not `ImageBackground`, also if you want to add a text on the `Image` component, you'll need to positioning that text with `position: 'absolute'` or `'relative'`

```
 <View style={postStyles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => his.props.navigation.navigate('AnotherWindow')}>}
    >
      <Image
        source={require('./my_image.png')}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{ width: '100%', height: 150, tintColor: 'cyan' }}
      />
      <Text style={postStyles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
        My text
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

Also, if you implement this approach you'll need to calculate the dimensions of the screen for each device, well you'll need to check this other component from react-native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions

Please, let me know if this works :D

Comment: if you want to change the background color of the image I'd prefer the image be on `.png` format and nesting the image component into a `View` component like:

```
<View styles={{ backgroundColor: 'yourColor' }}>
  <Image source={require('./your_image.png')} />
<View>
```
the `tintColor` prop change the color of the image itself
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: Hey Yasser, thanks for your answer! :)
In this way I can finally indeed affect the image.
The problem with tintColor is that indeed just colors the whole image and not just darkens it a bit as I wish.
The second solution of incorporating the image tag in a View tag with a background color property sadly doesn't work (doesn't affect the image at all)
I don't know if its because my picture is a jpg and not a png, but anyway I need to support jpg images as well.

Comment: Edit: Ha! I tried to play with the image's opacity and it did work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: tintColor prop works for ImageBackground too. It just should be applied to imageStyle not style.

Answer (score 17):

If anyone still having problems with the ImageBackground component, this is how i solved it, basically i set a view inside the image background which has the backgroundColor that darkens the image.

```
 <ImageBackground
      source={Images.background}
      style={styles.imageBackground}
    >
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
      {content}
      </View>
 </ImageBackground>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      imageBackground: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      },
      innerContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.60)'
      },
});
```

Comment: This is a much better answer since it keeps `<ImageBackground/>` component.

Answer (score 5):

You should just add tintColor to ImageBackground imageStyle and you're done. easy peasy!

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AnotherWindow')}>
    <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/my_img.jpg')} 
     style={{width: '100%', height: 150}}
     imageStyle={{tintColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'}}>
            <Text style={postStyles.title} numberOfLines={2}>
                My text
            </Text>
    </ImageBackground>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it just shows the tint color without image

Answer (score 0):

just add a View tag in your ImageBackground tag and give View tag css as
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'

```
              <ImageBackground
                style={styles.dAbstractSpaceSkyWithStarIcon}
                contentFit="cover"
                source={require('../../assets/3dabstractspaceskywithstarsnebula-1-12.png')}
              >
                <View style={styles.child}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{slokData[imageIndex].slok}</Text>
                </Text>
                </View>
              </ImageBackground>
```